# How does Apache keep clients from traversing the file system?

Tags: apache-2.2, filesystems

Since client URI requests to the server are just appended to the document root, what's to keep users from requesting things like, "../../bad_file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles) seems to tell how this can be prevented. A good way seems to be forbidding all access by default, then accepting it under the DocumentRoot.